# Is it 100% correct to replace !!someVar with Boolean(someVar)?

Tags: javascript, types

I am refactoring a bunch of old code and see that JSCS shows a warning about [implicit type conversion](http://jscs.info/rule/disallowImplicitTypeConversion) for !!someVar statements.

Is it correct to replace all these implicit conversions with Boolean(someVar) so that nothing breaks due to this change?

Comment: Doing the same in disguise doesn't strike as a good practice. Disabling that warning would be cleaner IMO. But your question isn't about opinion, I guess, and it's not clear to me. Are you asking whether the documentation you link to is faulty ?

Comment: No. The global `Boolean` variable might be overwritten/shadowed, the `!!` cannot.

Comment: Some linters look like they try too hard to justify their existence. Those "implicit type conversions" are standard, efficient and explicit enough practices.

Comment: @Bergi Can't pretty much any code be broken by overwriting and shadowing?

Comment: @Katana314 Operators in JS can't be shadowed, hopefully. The result of `!!someValue` is always a boolean.

Comment: @Katana314: Most, yes, but not all.

Comment: While static analysis tools are *immensely* valuable, some of their rules tend to be paranoid. Turning those off (I prefer to do so at the project level) is not a bad idea.

Comment: @ssube: It's not paranoia that is the reason for this rule, but "explicit is better than implicit" taken to the extreme. Turning it off might still be a good idea as it's only useful for newbies that don't know JS idioms.

Comment: @Bergi isn't "taken to the extreme" a good description of paranoia? The tool *should* have all of the rules that are *potentially* useful and allow you to pick the ones you want (that was the problem with jslint).

Comment: @ssube: I'd call that simply "extremism". The inverse rule, forcing the usage of operators and not trusting the globals (fearing they are compromised) would be "paranoid". But yes, either rule is not useful.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it 100% correct to replace `!!someVar` with `Boolean(someVar)`?

No. The global `Boolean` variable might be overwritten/shadowed, the [`!!` operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1048572) cannot.

> Is it correct to replace all these implicit conversions with `Boolean(someVar)` so that nothing breaks due to this change?

Yes. If your code breaks because of this change, it should be considered *already broken*, and you should fix the thing that messes with `Boolean` instead.

Answer (score -1):

As another option, you could disable that warning. Using truthiness/falsiness is pretty accepted in Javascript programming. Looks like you can just disable it for `boolean` and not the other types.