# Javascript ternary boolean shorthand

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Is there a shorthand syntax for the following JavaScript boolean ternary expression:

```
var foo = (expression) ? true : false
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you just want to cast your expression to a boolean:

```
var foo = Boolean(expression);
```

or [the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38593428/1048572) shortened to [double not operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1048572):

```
var foo = !! expression;
```

Comment: Could you explain the second solution ?

Comment: @Noob See the post link in Amy's comment. But it's simple logic.

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I was looking for.